# AVAudioPlayer's method 'play' does not work inside a while loop

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

i would like to play sound in a loop, with `AVAudioPlayer`, just like in metronome app, from ios examples. I have the following code:

```
BOOL continuePlaying = YES;

while(continuePlaying){

    [_audioPlayer play];
    ...do some other stuff
}
```

The problem is, that sound plays only once- during the first iteration. In next iterations play method doesn't seem to do anything. I would be grateful for any suggestions on what could be wrong.

**PS:** I know that `AVAudiopoayer` has `numberOfLoops` property, but in this case i want to do some other stuff between each plays, so i have to use a loop (i would like to create a metronome app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with this code, It worked for me:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
   while (continuePlaying)
   {
       [player play];
       //do your stuffs here
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and code. This works fine, but i still don't really understand why dispatching solves the problem. Could you please explain why AVAudioPlayer doesn't play a sound each time play method is executed, like i expected in my original code?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of playing while loop, capture delegate when ur sound finish playing

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
```

You can start playing sound again and do other stuff you would like to do.

Looping in case of playing sound seems illogical since you are firing multiple play and that wont work,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to create a metronome app, so playing sound in a loop is necessary in this case (i have just added this information to my original question).